Issues with Python application setting up Wi-Fi Hotspot using hostapd on Ubuntu
Question:
I'm trying to develop a Python application on Ubuntu that sets up a Wi-Fi hotspot (access point) and allows other devices to connect to it. Once connected, the server should communicate with the clients over this network.
What I've Done:
Wi-Fi Hotspot Setup:

    I'm using hostapd to create the Wi-Fi hotspot.

    dnsmasq is used to provide DHCP services.

    I've enabled IP forwarding and configured NAT using iptables.

Python Server:

    The server sets up the hotspot, starts hostapd and dnsmasq, and then listens for client connections.

    Once a client connects, it sends data to the client.

Problem:
The Wi-Fi hotspot appears to start correctly, but when a client device (another Ubuntu machine) tries to connect, the connection fails with an "Activation failed" message. Here's the relevant output from the server and client logs:
Server Side (Wi-Fi Hotspot Host):
Configuring IP forwarding...
IP forwarding enabled.
Setting up NAT with iptables...
NAT configured with iptables.
Restarting dnsmasq...
Dnsmasq stdout:
Dnsmasq stderr:
Restarting hostapd...
Hostapd stdout:
Hostapd stderr:
WiFi hotspot configured and started.
IP address for wlp0s20f3 is 10.1.1.90
Detected IP Address: 10.1.1.90
Prompting for timeout value...
Enter timeout value in seconds for sending messages: 10
Events loaded successfully.
Server listening on 10.1.1.90:10000
Application started, waiting for clients to connect.
Client Side (Attempting to Connect to Wi-Fi):
  [1723654413.1257] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
  [1723654413.2256] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
  [1723654432.1653] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
  [1723654432.1667] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'ABC_1234'
My Configuration Files:
hostapd.conf
interface=wlp0s20f3
driver=nl80211
ssid=ABC_1234
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=tech
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ap_max_inactivity=600
What I've Tried:
Double-checked the configuration of hostapd and dnsmasq.

Verified that hostapd and dnsmasq services are running without errors.

Ensured that the correct Wi-Fi interface (wlp0s20f3) is being used.

The Wi-Fi network "ABC_1234" is visible, but clients consistently fail to connect.

Question:
Why are client devices unable to connect to the Wi-Fi hotspot? How can I debug this issue further, and what might be the root cause of the "Activation failed" error on the client side?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
